# Script to compare the number of columns of different sheets on a Spreadsheet with App scripts

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

i have this code :

```
    function ordenar1() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  spreadsheet.setActiveSheet(spreadsheet.getSheetByName('DATOS'), true);
  spreadsheet.getActiveSheet().setFrozenRows(0);
  var sensoresintalados = spreadsheet.getRange("A1:A200").getNumColumns()
  var sheet = spreadsheet.getActiveSheet();
  sheet.getRange(1, 1, sheet.getMaxRows(), sheet.getMaxColumns()).activate();
  spreadsheet.getActiveSheet().sort(2, true);
  spreadsheet.setActiveSheet(spreadsheet.getSheetByName('smartsensor'))
  var numerosensores = sheet.getRange("B2:B200").getNumColumns() 
   if (sensoresintalados != numerosensores)
     Browser.msgBox('Actualiza la hoja de Smartsensor');
}
```

I want to show a message if the number of Columns is different but its not working.

I dont know if the problem is on the conditional or the way to count the number of columns

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### With `getNumColumns()` you query how many columns are inside a range you retrieve with `getRange("A1:A200")`...

- The obvious response is that this range contians only 1 column
- Same for the range `"B2:B200"`
- What you want isntead is to use the method [getDataRange()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getdatarange) that detects automatically the dimesions of the range containing data
- For a spreadsheet containing more than one sheet it is also important to apply the methods `getRange()` or `getDataRange()` to a sheet rather than spreadsheet in order to  make sure you you apply to the correct sheet

**In your case:**

- Replace

  `var sensoresintalados = spreadsheet.getRange("A1:A200").getNumColumns()`

  with

  `var sensoresintalados = spreadsheet.getActiveSheet().getDataRange().getNumColumns();`
- Replace

  `var numerosensores = sheet.getRange("B2:B200").getNumColumns()`

  with

  `var numerosensores = sheet.getDataRange().getNumColumns();`